# Breaking an array of equations

Tags: line-breaking, arrays, breqn

I wanted to break long equations in an `array` environment. To do this, I used `dmath` environment from `breqn` package but it did not work. How can I write long equations in an `array` environment with line breaks? My attempt is as follows:

[image: LaTex Output from ScribTex.com]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath*}
  L_{\lambda}(\phi, \omega) =
  \left\lbrace
      \begin{array}{ll}
        a \times b \times c \times d \times e \times f \times g \times h \times i \times j \times k \times l \condition[]{for $\phi$ even}, \\
        a \times b \times c \times d \times e \times f \times g \times h \times i \times j \times k \times l \condition[]{for $\phi$ odd},
      \end{array}
  \right.
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT: Actual Equation :

I thought the solution will be general so posted a nicer version of the problem earlier. Following is the actual equation I want to typeset. How can I typeset this equation nicely even with manual line breaks?
[image: output from scribtex.com]

```
\begin{dmath*}
  L_{\lambda}(\phi, \omega) =
  \left\lbrace
      \begin{array}{ll}
        2 \cos
        \left[
          \tanh \left(
            \frac{L_{\lambda-1}(\psi, \omega)}{2}
              \right) \times \tanh \left(
            \frac{L_{\lambda-1}(\psi, \omega+1)}{2}
              \right)
        \right] \condition[]{for $\phi$ even},
        \\
        2 \sin
        \left[
          \tanh \left(
            \frac{B_{\lambda-1}(\psi, \omega+1)}{2}
              \right) \times \tanh \left(
            \frac{L_{\lambda-1}(\psi, \omega)}{2}
              \right)
        \right] \condition[]{for $\phi$ odd},
      \end{array}
  \right.
\end{dmath*}
```

Comment: an array `l` column is always one line. You need (or could) use instead `p` columns of fixed width containing inline math $a \times b ....$ the inline math would wrap to the specified column width in standard latex even without breqn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As David Carlisle has already pointed out in a comment, you can't have a line break inside an `array` environment (at least not in a column of type `l`). The only possible break point in the equation you describe is right after the `L_{\lambda}(\phi, \omega)` part.

If the equation you've posted is really what you need to typeset -- I somehow doubt it, but that is what you've posted... -- your best bet may be to (i) replace all `\times` symbols with `\cdot` symbols and (ii) reduce the font size by 1 pt (by issuing the instruction `\small`) for the equation in question. (Note that I've also gotten rid of the `array` stuff in favor of a `cases*` environment.)

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,breqn} 
\usepackage{mathtools,breqn}
  \def\filler{Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, 
  sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo.
  Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies 
  et, tellus.}
\begin{document} 
{\small
\begin{dmath*}
L_{\lambda}(\phi, \omega) =
\begin{cases*}
a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot d\cdot e\cdot f\cdot g\cdot h\cdot i\cdot j\cdot 
   k\cdot l & for $\phi$ even, \\
a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot d\cdot e\cdot f\cdot g\cdot h\cdot i\cdot j\cdot 
   k\cdot l & for $\phi$ odd.
\end{cases*}
\end{dmath*}
} % end of scope of \small statement
\filler % filler text, to show width of text column
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, it would seem to be the case that you would rather have the line break (or breaks) occur somewhere to the *right* of the big curly brace. Here's a suggested solution which uses the `split` environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\def\filler{Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, 
  sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo.
  Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies 
  et, tellus.}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
   L_{\lambda}(\phi, \omega) =
   \begin{dcases}
      \begin{split}
         a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot d\cdot e\cdot f\cdot g \\
         {}\cdot h\cdot i\cdot j\cdot k\cdot l 
      \end{split}
      & \text{for $\phi$ even,} \\
      \begin{split}
         a\cdot b\cdot c\cdot d\cdot e\cdot f\cdot g \\
         {}\cdot h\cdot i\cdot j\cdot k\cdot l 
      \end{split}
      & \text{for $\phi$ odd.}
   \end{dcases}
\end{equation*}

\noindent\filler
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Addendum**: I just noticed that you posted the actual math expression you're trying to typeset. Here's how I would try to get the job done: building on the two previous examples, I'd allow a line break both after `L_{\lambda}(\phi, \omega)` -- fully automatic, courtesy of `breqn` and the `dmath*` environment -- *and* within each of the longish expressions to the right of the large curly brace. I would also use explicit `\biggl` and `\biggr` sizing instructions for the "fences" -- and not use `\left` and `\right`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,breqn}
\def\filler{Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod 
sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem 
non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis 
vitae, ultricies et, tellus.}
\begin{document}    
\begin{dmath*}
   L_{\lambda}(\phi, \omega) =
   \begin{dcases}
   \begin{aligned}[b]
   2 \cos \biggl[ \tanh\biggl(\frac{L_{\lambda-1}
        (\psi, \omega)}{2}\biggr) \ \ \ \ \ \\ 
        % need to "shove" the first line to the left
     \times \tanh\biggl(\frac{L_{\lambda-1}
        (\psi, \omega+1)}{2}\biggr) \biggr]
   \end{aligned} 
   & \text{for $\phi$ even,}\\
   \begin{aligned}[b]
   2 \sin\biggl[ \tanh\biggl( \frac{B_{\lambda-1}
        (\psi, \omega+1)}{2} \biggr) \\
     \times \tanh\biggl( \frac{L_{\lambda-1}
        (\psi, \omega)}{2} \biggr) \biggr]
   \end{aligned}
   & \text{for $\phi$ odd.}
   \end{dcases}
\end{dmath*}
\filler %% filler text (show width of text block)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not the equation I wanted to typeset but the problem is similar. So, I changed the messy equation with a nicer one. I thought there would be a general solution. Can we manually break lines with alignment similar to breqn?

Comment: @ubaabd: You can always insert a manual break. However, you need to be more clear in your question as to what exactly you're after in terms of that.

Comment: @ubaad: I've posted an addendum to show how one can use the `split` environment to force line breaks.

Comment: @Werner I posted the actual equation. How do you think should I manually line break this equation or what is the general trend that people follow with these kind of equations, as I suspect from your answers, there is no automatic way of doing this in Latex.

Comment: @mico Thanks Mico! Thats exactly what I wanted, i.e., proper alignment even after line breaks.

Comment: @Mico -- in the example with `\cdot`, the first one on the second line of each case is too close to the next variable.  put `{}` in front of it to get the spacing right.

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- wow, you do have very sharp eyes! I'll rerun the MWE to fix the spacing issue.