# Break line within array or eqnarray

Tags: arrays, multline, eqnarray

I have used the following codes to generate two equations. However, the second equation overlaps with the equation index. Can someone please help me look it pretty by breaking the 2nd equation into two lines? By the way, I also read on stackexchange to avoid eqnarray and instead use "array". Could you help me with that too? Apparently, using these codes within array resulted in error.

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\lambda_{R,t} &=& \dfrac{(C_{R,t}-\phi_c C_{R,t-1})^{-\sigma}} 
{P_t(1+\tau_t^c)} - \phi_c \beta \dfrac{(E_t C_{R,t+1}-\phi_c C_{R,t})^{- 
\sigma}}{P_t(1+\tau_t^c)} \\
Q_t &=& \beta E_t{(1-\delta)Q_{t+1} + \lambda_{R,t+1}R_{t+1}U_{t+1}(1- 
\tau^k_{t+1})} - \lambda_{R,t+1}P_{t+1} \left[\Psi_1(U_t-1) + \dfrac{\Psi_2} 
{2}(U_t-1)^2 \right]
\end{eqnarray}
```

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64103/121944

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment `align` is probably the way to go here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{align}
\lambda_{R,t} &= \dfrac{(C_{R,t}-\phi_c C_{R,t-1})^{-\sigma}} 
{P_t(1+\tau_t^c)} - \phi_c \beta \dfrac{(E_t C_{R,t+1}-\phi_c C_{R,t})^{- 
\sigma}}{P_t(1+\tau_t^c)} \\
Q_t &= \beta E_t{(1-\delta)Q_{t+1} + \lambda_{R,t+1}R_{t+1}U_{t+1}(1- 
\tau^k_{t+1})} \\ 
& - \lambda_{R,t+1}P_{t+1} \left[\Psi_1(U_t-1) + \dfrac{\Psi_2} 
{2}(U_t-1)^2 \right] \nonumber
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

You also have to use `\nonumber` in order to avoid having three equation numbers.

Hope that helps.

Romain

Comment: awesome! Exactly how I wanted it. Thank you Romain.

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion, with the `aligned` environment. You should not use `eqnarray`as it leads to bad spacing around the alignment points.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\lambda_{R,t} &= \dfrac{(C_{R,t}-\phi_c C_{R,t-1})^{-\sigma}}
{P_t(1+\tau_t^c)} - \phi_c \beta \dfrac{(E_t C_{R,t+1}-\phi_c C_{R,t})^{-
\sigma}}{P_t(1+\tau_t^c)} \\[1ex]
Q_t &=\raisetag{3.7ex} \begin{aligned}[t]
\beta E_t{(1-\delta)Q_{t+1} + \lambda_{R,t+1}R_{t+1}U_{t+1}(1-
\tau^k_{t+1})} & \hspace*{5cm}\\
 - \lambda_{R,t+1}P_{t+1} \Bigl[\Psi_1(U_t-1) + \dfrac{\Psi_2}
{2}(U_t-1)^2 \Bigr]
\end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` inside `align` ([never use `eqnarray`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\lambda_{R,t} &=
  \frac{(C_{R,t}-\phi_c C_{R,t-1})^{-\sigma}}{P_t(1+\tau_t^c)}
  - \phi_c \beta \frac{(E_t C_{R,t+1}-\phi_c C_{R,t})^{-\sigma}}{P_t(1+\tau_t^c)}
\\[1ex]
\begin{split}
Q_t &=
  \beta E_t{(1-\delta)Q_{t+1} + \lambda_{R,t+1}R_{t+1}U_{t+1}(1-\tau^k_{t+1})}
  \\
    &\qquad
  - \lambda_{R,t+1}P_{t+1} \Bigl[\Psi_1(U_t-1) + \frac{\Psi_2}{2}(U_t-1)^2 \Bigr]
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I used `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` because the size chosen by `\left and`\right`seems too large for this formula. The`[1ex]` helps in distinguishing between the two formulas.

[image]